# How do I vertically center a row within a column with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align my button vertically within its column. But the column height is not expanding to 100% of its parent row (the borders are just there to show the column height). How do I fix this?

Here's the url: https://skydocker.searchlightpro.us/main/userList

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code? I suspect you may have to add `h-100` to the `<div>` containing the columns

Answer (score 0):

h-100 on the outer row containing the primary columns would make the row expand to 100% of the parent container, right?

Nevertheless, here is the relevant code - I'm curious about this one too:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row border mt-2 ">
      <div class="col-sm-2 h-100">
         <img class="rounded-circle mx-auto align-self-center" src="Airy.png" alt="Avatar" width="140px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 h-100">
         <div class="row border align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
               <h5 class="mt-0">AKeoshiiProject</h5>
               <h6 class="font-italic">Keoshii Dex</h6>
               <p class="text-muted">Just here for the art.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
               <div class="my-auto">
                  <a href="https://AKeoshiiProject.searchlightpro.us" class="btn btn-primary">Go to their page!</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```